# Sentry: Remove querystring from URL

Tags: sentry

Does anyone know how to remove query string field (like token) from URL of error reported in Sentry?

Currenty, it is reported like:
https://sub.domain.com/test/?token=wead87j4odja&auth=test&id=5

And I would like it to be shown without token:
https://sub.domain.com/test/?auth=test&id=5

Comment: Why is this negative? I think it is a legitimate question. :/

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the organization Data Scrubbers?

https://docs.getsentry.com/hosted/learn/sensitive-data/

Comment: Yes, and I placed token in "Additional sensitive fields" but it still shows token in URL. :(